# Why does my analog oscilloscope have this weird waveform?

Tags: analog, noise, signal, oscilloscope

I have an analog oscilloscope.

When I connect the calibration signal, which is a square signal, I see that the signal fluctuates in this weird way. You can see that the signal has dips in the following pictures. The same thing happens even when the probe is not connected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144946/discussion-on-question-by-tombeki-why-does-my-analog-oscilloscope-have-this-weir); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Look like that scope is malfunctioning. The suggestions that the rectifier smoothing capacitors may be on their way out in the internal supplies are worth following up on.

As with any troubleshooting, start with the power supplies, first checking the ripple on the unregulated voltages, and then following by checking the regulator outputs.

**Beware of high voltages inside** - stay away from connections that go to the CRT. The CRT is a great capacitor for the anode charge, and will happily discharge itself through your body weeks or months after the scope was last powered on, depending on ambient humidity and the level of internal contamination. Anode voltage is in the kiloVolts to tens of kV. Don't mess with it - it's OK, otherwise you wouldn't get such otherwise reasonable-looking image on the tube.

Hopefully you can find a service manual for that scope, with schematics, whether online or a paper copy. It should include the specifications for internal supply voltages, including ripple.